# Making HTTP requests on button click

Tags: php, ajax, http, httpwebrequest

Need to make a HTTP request on click of a button on a webpage! , please guide me with an Example that whether using AJAX + PHP is the way out or Javascript will be able to do the same alone?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to bind onclick to the button

```
`onclick='location.href="mynewpage.html"`
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is actually part of JavaScript.

For simplicity, you might want to use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/).

Put this in the `<head>` section to load jQuery...

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

And to execute an AJAX request, include this too...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#id-of-your-button').onClick(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "backend.php"
    }).success(function(data) {
      // do something here
    });
}
</script>
```

For more details on this function, refer to [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) here.

Comment: so at //dp something here I need to put the http post request that i need